# PDF is replacing the apostrophe with an at sign in hebrew

Tags: pdf

I am using iTextSharp to fill pre-defined fields on an existing PDF document. all the apostrophes are replaced by an at sign in Hebrew words, I tried to embed the font to the document using Preflight but the embedding failed. How do I get the output PDF to display the text including the apostrophes? 
Thanks

Comment: Please add some examples to demonstrate an error.

Comment: the file and a picture with the text:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwdEVLBixCc7VlY3dzVsNVdGcDQ

Comment: You can see the file? i think the problem is that the font is ansi not unicode